# Octave console output doesn't display at real time

Tags: matlab, ide, octave

I have a piece of code in Octave (Matlab analog) of something like this:

```
c = 1;
for y = 1:rows
  for x = 1:cols

    printf('%d ', c);

    if (mod(c,10)==0)
      printf('\n');
    end

    c++;

    % some calculations here

  end
end
```

And i obviously expect a real time output of a counter value C to know how's the process going. But it doesn't seem to work. ALL the output appears right at the very end of whole program's done. Changing `printf` to `disp` doesn't help too.

My question is why is that?

Comment: disable the pager `more off` and/or flush stdout: `fflush(stdout)`